# Use [Authorize] in Controller with Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4

I'm working on .net core project that have 2 separated runnable applications WEB and IndentityServer. There is the tree of the project :

- API
- IdentityServer
- IdentityServert.LdapExtension
- Web

Identity Server 4 is used,

My problem here, is that Indentity Server is already configured and I need to put in place [Authorize] on Controller's routes inside API application and get info on User inside HttpContextAccessor.

IndentityServer Application got this config :

**Startup.cs**

```
        using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using IdentityServer.LdapExtension.Extensions;
using IdentityServer.LdapExtension.UserModel;
using IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Serilog.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IdentityServer
{
public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;
    private IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        X509SecurityKey? signingKey = null; 
        var isDevelopement = _env.IsDevelopment();

        //using (X509Store store = isDevelopement ? new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine) : new X509Store("WebHosting", StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var v = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);

            var v1 = new X509Certificate2Collection();

            v1 = v.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, isDevelopement ? "localhost" : _configuration["CertificateName"], !isDevelopement);
            if (v1.Count > 0)
            {
                signingKey = new X509SecurityKey(v1[0]);

                services.AddDataProtection();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new SecurityTokenInvalidSigningKeyException("Cannot find a valid certificate");
            }
        }

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("Default",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .WithHeaders("Authorization"); // Add this line to allow Authorization header
                }
            );
        });

        var credential = new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services
            .AddIdentityServer(o =>
            {
                o.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                o.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                o.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            })
            .AddSigningCredential(credential)
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(InMemoryInitConfig.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(InMemoryInitConfig.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryInitConfig.GetClients(_configuration))
            //.AddInMemoryClients(InMemoryInitConfig.Clients)
            .AddLdapUsers<FeiLdapUser>(_configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerLdap"), UserStore.InMemory);

        services.AddSingleton(_ => _configuration.GetSection("AccountOptions").Get<AccountOptions>());
        services.AddTransient<AccountService>();
        services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, SerilogLoggerFactory>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseCors(b => b.WithOrigins("http://localhost:51204"));
        //app.UseCors(b => b.WithOrigins("http://localhost:51204"));

        app.UseCors("Default");


        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        //app.UseCors(b => b.WithOrigins(_configuration.GetSection("CorsOrigins").Get<string[]>()));





        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

    }
}
}
```

**InMemoryInitConfig.cs**

```
    public class InMemoryInitConfig
{
    // scopes define the resources in your system
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("api", "FEI SMT API")
            {
                Scopes = { new Scope("api1") },
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return configuration.GetSection("IdentityClients").Get<Client[]>();

    }
}
```

The settings for IdentityClients inside appsettings.json

```
    "IdentityClients": [
  {
    "ClientId": "fei-smt",
    "ClientName": "FEI SMT Angular app",
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [
      "implicit",
      "client_credentials"
    ],
    "ClientSecrets": "secret",
    "AllowOfflineAccess":true,
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "RequireClientSecret": false,
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
    "AlwaysSendClientClaims": false,
    "AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken": false,
    "RedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:51204/auth-callback"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "http://localhost:51204/"
    ],
    "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
      "http://localhost:51204"
    ],
    "AllowedScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "api",
      "api1"
    ],
    "AccessTokenLifetime": 3600
  }
],
```

And inside the Web application

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program {

    private static IConfiguration Configuration;
    private static Program _instance;

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        Start();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }


    public static IHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
                    .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                 

                    .UseSerilog()
                ;

                //webBuilder.Build();
            });


    private static void Start()
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");


        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.override.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        // Start program
        _instance = new Program();
        _instance.Run(Configuration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private async Task Run(IConfiguration config)
    {


        //_config = config.EnsureArgumentNotNull(nameof(config));

        try
        {
            // Create Token manager
            var tkmgr = new TokenManager();

            // Get Token from Identity Server
            var tokenResponse = await tkmgr.RequestTokenAsync();
            if (tokenResponse.IsError)
            {
                // Authentication has failed
                //$"Invalid token: {tokenResponse.Error}".WriteLineRed();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                // Get the base endpoint
                //var apiBaseAddress = _config["APIBaseAddress"];


                var am = new APIManager(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
                am.BaseAddress = "http://localhost:51204";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }

    }
}
```

**APIManager.cs**

```
    public class APIManager
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; private set; }

    private string _baseAddress = string.Empty;

    public string BaseAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return _baseAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            _baseAddress = value;
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
        }
    }

    public APIManager(string accessToken)
    {
        Client = new HttpClient();
        Client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
    }
}
```

**TokenManager.cs**

```
    public class TokenManager
{
    public TokenManager()
    {}

    public async Task<TokenResponse> RequestTokenAsync()
    {
        //specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;
        //Get endpoint to obtain a token
        var client = new HttpClient();


        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44356/.well-known/openid-configuration");

        if (disco.IsError) throw new Exception(disco.Error);

        var response = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(
            new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
            {
                Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = "fei-smt",
                Scope = "api",
                ClientSecret = "secret"
            });

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public class Startup {

    private readonly HttpClientStartupState _httpClientState;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
        //_httpClientState = httpClientState;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

        services.AddDbContext<SmtContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
                                            x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", "smt")));
        services.AddDbContext<MasterContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                                            x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__EFMigrationsHistory", "smt")));

        //services.AddMvc(options =>
        //{
        //    // Default auth policy for API routes
        //    //var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        //    //    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        //    //    .Build();
        //    //options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        //});
        //.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
        //.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => {
            configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot";
        });

        // Security


        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://localhost:44356";
            //options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandlerAdapter(_httpClientState.HttpClient);

            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });




        //services.AddHttpClient();





        // DI
        //services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        //services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
        //services.AddSingleton<CustomHttpContextAccessor>();
        //services.AddScoped<TokenService>();


        services.AddScoped<IProjectsService, ProjectsService>();
        services.AddScoped<IApplicationFormService, ApplicationFormService>();
        services.AddScoped<IEventsService, EventsService>();
        services.AddScoped<IHomeService, HomeService>();
        services.AddScoped<IDocumentsService, DocumentsService>();
        services.AddScoped<IAdministrationService, AdministrationService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }



        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        //app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseCors("Default");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Anguzlar SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //   spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            //}
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that I have always 401 Unauthorize when I try to call this route inside API :

```
        [HttpGet("subTypes")]
    [Authorize]
    [ProducesResponseType(200)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllProjectSubTypes()
    {
        var dtos = (await dataContext.ProjectSubTypes
            .Include(t => t.ProjectType)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Pillar)
            .ToListAsync())
            .ToDTOs<ProjectSubTypesDTO>()
            .OrderBy(t => t.Name);
        return Ok(dtos);
    }
```

When the front is making a call to the route, I need to be able to get the User from the context and be authorized to use this route inside API.

If you have any idea how to resolve this issue I will be gratefull.

I think my problem is that I cannot store the acess_token in HttpClient returned from IdentityServer (My token is returned well, I already put a breakpoint at this stage to know if I got him).

And if I make a request via Postman with Bearer Token returned from Identity Server it's working well, I got the results from the API route.

Regards,

Comment: Perhaps my blogpost here can help? https://nestenius.se/2023/06/02/debugging-jwtbearer-claim-problems-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Hello @ToreNestenius, Thanks for your answer, 

In the debug it says that the token is not provided, so that's my issue, how to fixe that ?